# Inheritance vs. Composition in Python for this specific case?

Tags: python, inheritance, combinations

Assume I have a series of classes as follows:

```
class A(object):
    __init__(self,a):
        self.a=a
class B(A):
    __init__(self,a,b):
        super(B,self).__init__(a)
        self.b=b
class C(A):
    __init__(self,a,c1,c2):
        super(C,self).__init__(a)
        self.c1=c1
        self.c2=c2
```

If now D is a both B and C, it can be implemented as

```
class D(B,C)
    __init__(self,a,b,c1,c2,d):
        pass
```

Or `D` can be understood as a combination of `B` and `C`

```
class D(B,C)
    __init__(self,a,b,c1,c2,d):
        self.b=B(a,b)
        self.c=C(a,c)
```

which seems a bit more complicated than the multi-inheritance case.

Well, Now let's imaging `class D2` is a combination of 5 pieces of `B` and 3 pieces of `C`, and `class D3` is made of `D2` plus an additional `C`(with different parameter than the ones in `D`), and `D4` is made of `D2` and 2 additional pieces of `C`(these 2 additional `C` has same parameter but different from the ones in `D2`). It seems `D2` is good to use composition, but `D3` is good to use inheritance of `D2` and `C`, and `D4` is good to use inheritance of `D2` and `C`.

Use combinations, to me, has the disadvantage that I have to write `d.c.c1` rather than `d.c1`(as in inheritance case)to get the parameter `c` or I need to store the parameter `c` in D directly(besides the one as `d.c.c1`). Is there any philosophical consistent way to deal with these classes? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're bound to get some level of opinion on a question like this -- My answer is to use inheritance *iff* your classes are designed to be inherited.  Use composition in all the other cases.  In practice, this usually means that if the code that you are extending exists in a realm out of your control, don't subclass it unless their documentation talks about *how* you can subclass it effectively.

In this case, since it seems like you are the author of the class hierarchy, inheritance seems to make sense (though some of your assertions are incorrect -- `D` is not so easy to implement as you have supposed since none of the superclass `__init__` will get called).  You probably should familiarize yourself with the design pattern in Raymond Hettinger's ["super considered super" article](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.b = b

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, c1, c2, **kwargs):
        super(C, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.c1 = c1
        self.c2 = c2
```

*now* the implementation of `D` is trivially simple:

```
class D(B, C):
    pass
```

Note that we don't even need to define `__init__` because all of the constructors of the super classes can accept arbitrary keyword arguments.  Instantiating a `D` looks like:

```
d = D(a='a', b='b', c1='c1', c2='c2')
```

Comment: Thank you @mgilson, but actually the implementation of `class D` is not the most concerned here(this is another question I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187040/python-multi-inheritance-with-parent-classes-have-different-init). The current question is about the how to implement the  `D2 `, `D3 `, `D4 `, which have small difference. The essential mysteries to me is if one thing(for instance  `D `) has  a `B ` and a `C `, it could be derived  from  `B ` and  `C `, but if  ` D` has a `B ` and two `C `s, do we have to use composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: 'super(c, self)' should be 'super(C, self)'.